# React Bootstrap NavDropdown alignRight not working

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm using react bootstrap and trying to align NavBar menus to the right

```
<Nav className="ml-auto paddingLeft5" alignRight>
    <NavDropdown title="Account" id="basic-nav-dropdown" alignRight>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/privacySettings">Privacy Settings</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/signOut">Sign Out</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
    <NavDropdown title="Help" id="basic-nav-dropdown" alignRight>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/contactUs">Contact us</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="/termsAndConditions">Terms and Conditions</NavDropdown.Item>
    </NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

However this seems to not work. I'm using "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.10", "react-dom": "^16.8.4" and "bootstrap": "^4.3.1".

the result can be seen in the attached image. [image]

I can't manage to align the menu to the right, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of this?

Comment: Trying, i don't have much experience with it so might take a while

Comment: Sure thing, just tag me when it's ready.

Comment: It's caused by the MDBreact imports, added link(https://codesandbox.io/s/code-sandbox-examples-n6d1b?fontsize=14) @Train Though not sure how to fix it

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at it as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 10):

```
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap'
<Nav className="ml-auto">
<NavDropdown alignRight title="Profile" id="collasible-nav-dropdown" >
<NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
<NavDropdown.Divider />
<NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
</Nav>
```

Kill port number manually using command `netstat -ntlp` then use `kill -9 <port number>` and start server using `npm start`.

Answer (score 5):

Came across this question today again and wanted to contribute that with:

```
"react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0"  
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3"
```

you can use the `align="end"` attribute in NavDropdown component

```
<NavDropdown align="end" title="Dropdown" id="nav-add">
  <NavDropdown.Item onClick={() => showAddDialog(true)}>Add</NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Divider />
  <NavDropdown.Item onClick={() => showAddImageDialog(true)}>Add Image</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

Reference:
[Menu alignment](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/dropdowns/#menu-alignment)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you could do in css or boostrap

with plain css you could create these styles

```
.custom_nav_link{
  align-self: flex-end!important;  // or  text-align: end !important;
}
```

You could also put in these classes out of the box

```
align-self-end`
align-self-sm-end //also works with md, lg
```

This aligns everything to the right if you add them to your nav links

which gives you this

[image]

and here is the new html

```
  <div>
    <Navbar collapseOnSelect expand="lg" bg="dark" variant="dark">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
      <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
        <Nav className="mr-auto">
          <Nav.Link className="custom_nav_link" href="#features">Features</Nav.Link>
          <Nav.Link className="custom_nav_link" href="#pricing">Pricing</Nav.Link>
          <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" className="custom_nav_link" id="collasible-nav-dropdown">
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">
              Another action
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Divider />
            <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">
              Separated link
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
        <div className="searchBar-inline">
          <div className="input-group md-form form-sm form-1 pl-0">
            <div className="input-group-prepend">
              <span
                className="input-group-text purple lighten-3"
                id="basic-text1"
              >
                <MDBIcon className="text-white" icon="search" />
              </span>
            </div>
            <input
              className="form-control my-0 py-1"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Search"
              aria-label="Search"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Nav className="ml-auto paddingLeft5">
          <NavDropdown title="Account" className="custom_nav_link" id="basic-nav-dropdown" alignRight>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/privacySettings">
              Privacy Settings
            </NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/signOut">Sign Out</NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
          <NavDropdown title="Help" className="custom_nav_link" id="basic-nav-dropdown" alignRight>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/contactUs">Contact us</NavDropdown.Item>
            <NavDropdown.Item href="/termsAndConditions">
              Terms and Conditions
            </NavDropdown.Item>
          </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
      </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
  </div>
```

Your nav bar takes up the entire width which looks wierd. So if you want to change it you can do just make the container smaller and move it fixed or absolute to the right.